# Why does the 'break' in this Python code end the program?

Tags: python, break

I am trying to make a simple guessing game, but the program exits when the user answers, 'yes', that they know how to play. I don't understand why the 'break' makes the program exit rather than continue to the rest of the code. Extreme newbie, in case you can't tell :P
Thanks for all the help!

```
import random
import time
def calculat(times):
    p = "."
    for nums in range(times):
        print p
        time.sleep(.2)
        print p * 2
        time.sleep(.2)
        print p * 3
        time.sleep(.2)
        print p * 2
        time.sleep(.2)
    print p
    time.sleep(.6)


print "Welcome to Guess!"
print "Press [Enter] to continue!"
raw_input()



while True:
    know = raw_input("Do you know how to play? Enter [yes] or [no]\n")
    know = know.upper()
    if know == "YES":
        break
    elif know == "NO":
        print " "
        print "-INSTRUCTIONS-"
        print "Here's how the game works. A number 1 to 100"
        print "is generated randomly. Your goal is to guess"
        print "as many numbers as possible before you run"
        print "out of guesses. You have 10 guesses.Good luck!"
        print "Have fun!"
    else:
        print "Please enter [yes] or [no]!"

while True:
    score = 0
    number = randint(1,100)
    newnum = 1

    for tries in range(0,9):
        if newnum == 1:
            print "Okay, I have a number 1 to 100! What is it?"
        else:
            print "Guess again! What's the number?"

        while True:
            try:
                guess = input()
                if guess <= 100 and guess >= 1:
                    break
                else:
                    print "You must guess an integer, 1 - 100!"
            except:
                print "You must guess an integer, 1 - 100!"

        if guess == number:
            print "Heyo! That's correct!"
            score = score + 1
            number = randint (1,100)
            newnum = 1
            if tries != 9:
                print "Press [Enter]! Guess another number!"
            raw_input()

        elif guess < number:
            if tries != 9:
                print "Darn, that guess was less than the number! Try again!"
                print "Press [Enter] to continue!"
            raw_input()

        elif guess > number:
            if tries != 9:
                print "Whoa, that guess is too big! Try again!"
                print "Press [Enter] to continue!"
            raw_input()

    print "That's it! Let me calculate your final score! [Press Enter]"
    raw_input()
    calculate(4)
    print "Final Score: " + score
    print "Good job!"
    raw_input()
    print "Would you like to play again? [yes] or [no]?"
    play = raw_input()
    play = play.upper()
    if play == "NO":
        print "Okay then, press enter to exit!"
        raw_input()
        break
    elif play == "YES":
        print "Yey! Let me think of a new number!"
        calculate(2)
    else:
        print "You couldn't even say yes or no. Get out."
        raw_input()
        break
```

Oh yeah, the rest of the code could be broken, too. I haven't gotten past the instructions part.

Comment: When I run the code and enter "Yes", it exits with an error message.  Did you try reading the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It ends the program because it immediately encounters an error after the instructions are finished. You've imported `random` but then tried to use `randint`, unqualified. You've got to qualify it as `random.randint` or use `from random import randint`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the `break` statement to escape from the first infinite loop. When I run your code, that `break` statement works just fine and control proceeds to the second infinite while loop.

However, your program then crashes on the first call to `randint()` because you aren't importing it correctly. Since the `randint()` function is from outside of your program (it's in the `random` module), you need to  qualify the calls to `randint()` as `random.randint()` - so for the first call, you could use `number = random.randint(1, 100)`. Alternatively, you could import randint using `from random import randint`, rather than `import randint`. That way, you would be able to call `randint()` directly.